# Debugging while using dotnet watch

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-7.0

I have a problem with settings the correct launchsettings to enable both hotreload and debugging at the same time,
having the following profile works fine with tracking required cshtml changes but disable all breakpoints, however changing the commandName to Project enable the breakpoints again but doesnt reload or track any changes

`"Watch": { "commandName": "Executable", "executablePath": "dotnet", "commandLineArgs": "watch run", "launchBrowser": true, "hotReloadEnabled": true, "dotnetRunMessages": true, "nativeDebugging": true, "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)", "environmentVariables": { "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" }, "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7092;http://localhost:5215" }`

I am using .Net 7, Web Application, Output type is Console App

being Able to track cshtml changes and debug

**Update**
I am using VS 2022 Community Edition

Comment: Are you using VS or VSCode?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention VS 2022 community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this profile works fine with both track changes in cshtml and debugging using breakpoint

```
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  }
},
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3853",
    "sslPort": 44376
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can make it mark so that it can help more people